# Need help creating buttons in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

I have been assigned a homework problem in pygame to make two rectangles, one red , one green and when clicked, text appears which gives the name of the colour of the button, I have created the shapes successfully, however I don't know how to make the text appear when the button is clicked. Any help is appreciated

I have successfully drawn two rectangles using the pygame.draw.rect() function and I have called pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() in order to get an x and y value for the user's mouse.

```
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x = pos[0]
y = pos[1]

screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [100, 300, 200, 200])
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [400, 300, 200, 200])

pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(60)
```

The result is two rectangles, one green, one red in the centre of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify if amouse button is pressed oyu can use [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed):

```py
leftClicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
```

For text rendering you can use [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) or [`pygame.pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html). e. g:

```py
import pygame.freetype
```

```py
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
```

Define a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for each button:

```py
rect_green = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 200, 200)
rect_red   = pygame.Rect(400, 300, 200, 200)
```

Verify if the mouse button is pressed an the mouse coursor is on the button by [`.collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint)). e.g.:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rectGreen)
if leftClicked and rectGreen.collidepoint(pos):
    text_surf, text_rect = font.render("GREEN", WHITE, size=30)
    text_rect.center = rectGreen.center 
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)
```

See the short example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

pygame.init()
size = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)

rect_green = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 200, 200)
rect_red   = pygame.Rect(400, 300, 200, 200)

def DrawButton(surf, cursor_pos, pressed, rect, color, text_color, text):
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, rect)
    if pressed and rect.collidepoint(cursor_pos):
        text_surf, text_rect = font.render(text, text_color, size=30)
        text_rect.center = rect.center 
        screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    leftClicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    DrawButton(screen, pos, leftClicked, rect_green, GREEN, BLACK, "GREEN")
    DrawButton(screen, pos, leftClicked, rect_red, RED, BLACK, "RED")
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!